# reactjs : ShouldComponentUpdate for states

Tags: reactjs

How can I use `shouldComponentUpdate` for states?

I can check:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  return this.state.value != nextState.value;
}
```

But it doesn't have any sense for states. Because if I change state(`this.setState({value: 'newValue'})`) `this.state` will be equal  `nextState`.

For example, `onClick` event:

```
handleClick() {
  this.setState({value: 'newValue'});
}
```

Comment: the components should simply rerender when its state changes, I thought the [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate) is mainly for the props, not the states. From the [specs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate) you can see that you can decide wether the new state warrants a component update, for example, you might have logic that doesn't need to update the current state, but you cannot compare it with the previous state as you can with props

Comment: @Icepickle, In my case I want to compare states because my component doesn't get `props` but a parent component re-render it.

Comment: Compare states and decide whatever you'd like update it in the place where you actually change it

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` method works for both props and state. In your example, after the `onClick` event the following method is fired by React.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  return this.state.value != nextState.value;
}
```

The key here is that in the above method the value of `this.state.value` is equal to what it was **before** the `setState()` call. This is thanks to the fact that in React:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. 
>   React docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate

Have a look at this demo: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/YGZgom (full code below)

React keeps on state the count of every click on the button and also saves the randomly picked `value` (true or false). However thanks to the  `shouldComponentUpdate` method, the component is re-rendered only if the **previous** `value` is not equal to upcoming / new `value`. This is why the displayed click count sometimes skips rendering its current state. You can comment out the whole `shouldComponentUpdate` method to  re-render on every click.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: true,
      countOfClicks: 0
    };
    this.pickRandom = this.pickRandom.bind(this);
  }

  pickRandom() {
    this.setState({
      value: Math.random() > 0.5, // randomly picks true or false
      countOfClicks: this.state.countOfClicks + 1
    });
  }

  // comment out the below to re-render on every click
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return this.state.value != nextState.value;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        shouldComponentUpdate demo 
        <p><b>{this.state.value.toString()}</b></p>
        <p>Count of clicks: <b>{this.state.countOfClicks}</b></p>
        <button onClick={this.pickRandom}>
          Click to randomly select: true or false
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Thanks. That's strange because I set 'value: ''' in `constructor`. And after `onClick` event I get `this.state.value` is `newValue` in `shouldComponentUpdate`. But I thought it should be `this.state.value = '', nextState.value = 'newValue'`.

Comment: Have a look at the console output here: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/LRdppQ.   The initial value is `0` and therefore when you click the button `this.state.countOfClicks` is `0` and `nextState.countOfClicks` is `1`. You can also see that  inside `shouldComponentUpdate` `this.state.countOfClicks` is always lagging behind what is actually rendered on screen. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, I tested your example. It works. But in my real project `this.state` is equal to `nextState`. That's strange. Keep looking. Maybe I did something wrong. Thank you.

Comment: You may be mutating the state directly. Here are some hints: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1388

Comment: Yes, thanks. I change state before I call `setState`. `let state = this.state; state.value = 'newValue'; this.setState(state)`;

Comment: Instead of the above, update your state in the following way: `this.setState({
      value: 'newValue'
    });`  That's it. Here is a simple demo: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/GjdgJK

Comment: This is a great example!