# React: delay in input changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a rather big array of objects in the parent component's state. And when I pass them as props to children components (which don't have state, only props) I have a huge delay in typing (in children's components) when the input changes.

I have already read answers on similar questions [ReactJS delay onChange while typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53071774/reactjs-delay-onchange-while-typing) and advice to use shouldcomponentupdate [reactjs : ShouldComponentUpdate for states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926968/reactjs-shouldcomponentupdate-for-states/39928279) .

But, unfortunately, I still **didn't understand how to apply it in my example**:  https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-8vlc2 . Parent component is index.js . So:

1) Should I use componentdidupdate or shouldcomponentupdate()  in children's components (StoryList.tsx and StoriesScreenItem/StoriesScreenList) ?

2) Should I add state in children's component to use componentdidupdate or shouldcomponentupdate() ?

3) Why does the input delay happen in my example?

4) Or any other ideas how can I manage this problem?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think the [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53071774/reactjs-delay-onchange-while-typing) applies here, as it seems the action you want to delay is updating the state. This would result in the textfields not reflecting the actual text contained in the state.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a functional component for a story.

It could look something like this:

```
export const Story = props => {
   const [story, setStory] = useState(props.story);
   const handleChange = e => {
       const updatedStory = {...story};
       updatedStory.caption = e.target.value;
       setStory(updatedStory);
   };
   return (
       <div>
           <div>
               <div>
                   {story.previewUri ? (
                       <div>
                           <img
                               style={{
                               objectFit: "cover",
                               border: "4px solid #1ec1b6"
                            }}
                            width="110"
                            height="168"
                            src={story.previewUri || null}
                            alt={"Фото сториc"}
                        />
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    <div
                        style={{
                            border: "4px solid #1ec1b6",
                            textAlign: "center",
                            fontSize: "14px"
                        }}
                    >
                        Link image
                    </div>
                )}

                <div>
                    <span>Story</span>

                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <span>Preview title</span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input
                                style={{ width: "100%" }}
                                maxLength={99}
                                value={story.caption}
                                onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <StoriesScreenList
                screens={story.stories}
                onChange={screens => props.changeScreen(screens, props.index)}
            />
           </div>
       </div>
    );
};
export default Story;
```

Each of these would have their own state, so you would not have to update the entire array of stories each time a single story is changed.

Which is suspect is what creates the delay.

I Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks! But in my project, we don't use hooks :( If I do everything like this but using state and setState, it is ok?

Comment: I believe using state and setState. Should work fine

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't help me but anyway thank you very much for paying attention to my problem!:).  I decided to set "focus: false" in state and update children's components only when their's inputs (or selects) get focus.

Comment: @JANE DOE it's great you found a solution. You should write what you did in an answer and accept it, so others can learn from your experience.